# Can I choose $E/\mathbb{F}_q$ so that $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q) = a$ for any $a \in \{1,\dots,q^2 \}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Does there exist an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{F}_q$ such that $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)=a$ for any $a\in \{1,\dots,q^2 \}$?

I'm trying to use an argument where I first fix my base field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and then I must find an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{F}_q$ where $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is equal to some constant depending on my choice of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Is there some general theorem that tells me this is always possible?

EDIT: Fixed for any $a\in \mathbb{F}_q^\times$ to $a\in \{1,\dots,q^2 \}$.

EDIT 2: What about $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q) =a \mod \ell$ for some prime $\ell \neq p$ and $a\in \mathbb{F}_l$?

Comment: (1) The size of a set is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, you can't have this equality you write down. (2) If $q = p$ and you are taking the lift with $a \in [1, p] \cap \mathbb{Z}$ then the answer is no, Hasse's theorem gives a bound that $|\#E(\mathbb{F}_q) - (q + 1)|  \leq 2\sqrt{q}$

Comment: If $gcd(a, q)=1$ and $|a - (q+1)| \leq 2 \sqrt q$, then there is an elliptic curve $E / F_q$ with $a$ points over $F_q$. See Waterhouse "Abelian varieties over finite fields", theorem 4.1.

Comment: @Watson Thanks for this comment. I think this answers the question posed in my second edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q$ be a prime power. Let $t$ be an integer such that $\gcd(t, q)=1$ and $|t| \leq 2 \sqrt q$, then there is an elliptic curve $E / F_q$ with $(q+1) - t$ points over $F_q$.
See Waterhouse's paper (PhD thesis) ["Abelian varieties over finite fields"](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=ASENS_1969_4_2_4_521_0) theorem 4.1. for a more general statement.

When $q=p$, any non-zero integer $t$ such that $|t| \leq 2 \sqrt p$ must be coprime to $p$, so there is an elliptic curve $E / \mathbb F_p$ with $p+1-t$ points. This is also true when $t=0$.
When $q=p$, this was proved by Deuring (1941). A modern treatment is given in Cox's book "Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$", theorem 14.18.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The question is seriously editted so that the following answer no longer makes sense.

---

By [Hasse's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves), we always have $|\#E(\Bbb F_q) - q - 1| \leq 2\sqrt{q}$. This means that $\#E(\Bbb F_q)$ can take about $4\sqrt q$ different values, which cannot cover the whole $\Bbb F_q^\times$ for large $q$.

Comment: Sorry for editing the question :( I will be more careful next time before I post